# $G[n] = \{x \in G|nx = 0\}$ Prove that there are only finitely many subgroups $H$ of order $p^m$ in $G$ if $G[p]$ is finite;

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an additive abelian group such that multiplication by $n$: $x \mapsto nx$ is surjective for all positive integers $n$. Let
$$G[n] = \{x \in G|nx = 0\}$$
and $p$ be a prime.

Prove that for a given integer $m \geq 1$, there are only finitely many subgroups $H$ of order $p^m$ in $G$ if $G[p]$ is finite;

I was thinking that each subgroup $H$ of order $p^m$ gives a distinct element $x \in G$ such that $px = 0$? But not sure how to go about showing this.

Comment: Make an induction

Comment: By the [structure theorem of divisible groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group#Structure_theorem_of_divisible_groups), $G\cong\left(\bigoplus_{q\in \mathbf P} \mathbb Z[q^\infty]^{(I_q)}\right) \oplus \mathbb Q^{(I)}.$ Since $G[p]$ is finite, so is $I_p,$ whence the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

As an example, let us prove that if for an abelian group $G$ the set $G[p]$ is finite, then $G[p^2]$ is also finite. Since $G[p]$ and $G[p^2]$ are subgroups of the group $G$ and the mapping $f: \,x\to px$ is a homomorphism of the group $G[p^2]$ to the group $G[p]$, it follows that  the factor group $G[p^2]/\operatorname{Ker}(f)$ isomorphic to some subgroup of the group $G[p]$ and since $\operatorname{Ker}(f)<G[p]$, then $\operatorname{Ker}(f)$ is finite and hence $G[p^2]$ is also finite.

Next, induction works, as noted in the comment.